# How to design relational database for conferences and workshops

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have to design a database (as a homework for university), for company which organises conferences. 
In these conferences can participate private customers or organizations (each organization can sign up few people). 
Currently I need some advices how to finish my project because my teacher said that it is quite incorrect.

Here is short description:

- Some company organizes conferences which can take one or more days
- Customers should register via www website
- Customer is an individual person or an organization, but attendee of conference is a person
- organizations can reserve some space for conferences, but 2 weeks before conference starts these infomations should be filled
- for conferences which takes more then one day, customer can sign up for any day (for example only for first day)
- Moreover, with conferences are connected workshops (customers can participate workshops as well) BUT ONLY WHEN THEY are registred for conference at this day (conference-day has many workshops)
- there is limited space for conferences and workshops

@Payments

- payment for conference/workshop depends on :

  1. if attendee is a student -  he has some discount
  2. as earlier attendee will sign up for conference then discount will be bigger

Here is my schema, which i designed few days ago.

[image].

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having a hard time following your diagram.

A relational database is [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Since the database is about conferences and workshops, let's start with those tables.  As you create each table, check to make sure that it meets the criteria that you (or your user) outlined.

### Conference Table

```
Conference
----------
Conference ID
Conference Name
Conference Description
Conference Total Attendees
Conference Start Date
Conference End Date
Conference Total Price
Conference Day Price
```

Table names are usually singular.  This is the information that the conference company needs to book a conference.  Next, we'll look at workshops.

### Workshop Table

```
Workshop
--------
Workshop ID
Conference ID
Workshop Name
Workshop Description
Workshop Total Attendees
Workshop Date
Workshop Price
```

The Conference ID ties the workshop back to the conference.  The workshop date must fall in between the conference start date and the conference end date (inclusive).

Notice that we haven't even considered customers yet.  We've just created the tables that the conference company needs to manage its conferences and workshops.

Here are the requirements that we've covered so far:

- Some company organizes conferences which can take one or more days
- There is limited space for conferences and workshops

Now, let's take a look at the discounts.

### Discount Table

```
Discount
--------
Discount ID
Discount Type
Discount Description
Discount Percentage
```

This table will hold the discounts for students and early registration.  There's one row for each type of discount.  There can be several early registration discounts.

Here are the requirements that we've covered so far:

- Student discount
- Early registration discount

Now, we're ready to tackle customers and registrants.

### Customer Table

```
Customer
--------
Customer ID
Customer Name
Customer Organization
Customer Address
Customer City
Customer State
Customer Postal Code
Customer Country Code
```

The customer can be an individual (organization is blank or null) or a person representing an organization.

At this point, we haven't tied customers to conferences.  Since there are many customers for a conference (we hope), and (we hope) many conferences for a customer, we need a junction table.

### Reservation Table

```
Reservation
-----------
Reservation ID
Customer ID
Conference ID
Reservation Date
Payment Date
Early Registration Discount
Total Conference Cost 
Number of Attendees
```

This table allows a customer to register for a conference.  We need a table to hold the attendee information.

### Attendee Table

```
Attendee
--------
Attendee ID
Reservation ID
Attendee Name
Attendee Address
...
Discount
Attendee Cost
```

We've tied the attendees to the conference, but not to the days of the conference or any workshops.  For this, we need a couple more junction tables.

### Conference Attendance Table

```
Conference Attendance
---------------------
Conference Attendance ID
Attendee ID
Conference ID
Conference Attendance Date
```

The Conference Attendance Date must fall in between the conference start date and the conference end date (inclusive).

### Workshop Attendance Table

```
Workshop Attendance
-------------------
Workshop Attendance ID
Attendee ID
Workshop ID
Conference Attendance ID
Workshop Attendance Date
```

The Workshop Attendance Date must be the same as the Conference Attendance date.  The Workshop Attendance Date is not necessary.  You could get the Conference Attendance Date through thee Conference Attendance ID.  We keep the Workshop Attendance Date for query convenience.

Here are the requirements that we've covered so far:

- Customer is an individual person or an organization, but attendee of conference is a person
- Organizations can reserve some space for conferences, but 2 weeks before conference starts this information should be completed
- For conferences which take more then one day, attendee can sign up for any day (for example only for first day)
- Conferences have connected workshops (attendees can participate workshops as well) BUT ONLY WHEN THEY are registered for conference at this day (conference day has many workshops)

It looks like we covered all the requirements.  The web software that uses this database will have to enforce some of the time and discount constraints.